# Where’s the at::empty() source code of PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

```
> Tensor empty(
>     IntArrayRef size,
>     c10::optional<DimnameList> names,
>     c10::optional<ScalarType> dtype,
>     c10::optional<Layout> layout,
>     c10::optional<Device> device,
>     c10::optional<bool> pin_memory,
>     optional<MemoryFormat> optional_memory_format) {   // See [Note: hacky wrapper removal for TensorOptions]   TensorOptions options =
> TensorOptions().dtype(dtype).layout(layout).device(device).pinned_memory(pin_memory);
> 
>   if (!names.has_value()) {
>     return at::empty(size, options, optional_memory_format);   }   TORCH_CHECK(options.layout() == Layout::Strided,
>       "NYI: named tensors only support strided layout");   TORCH_CHECK(options.device().is_cpu() || options.device().is_cuda(),
>       "NYI: named tensors only support CPU and CUDA tensors");   auto result = at::empty(size, options, optional_memory_format);  
> internal_set_names_inplace(result, names);   return result; }
```

I just found this in PyTorch source code but there is nothing about `at::empty(size, options, optional_memory_format)`.

So where is the source code of `at::empty(size, options, optional_memory_format)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the definition of empty() in pytorch/build/aten/src/ATen/ops/empty.h
(It means that you should have to build PyTorch firstly)

```
inline at::Tensor empty(at::IntArrayRef size, at::TensorOptions options={}, c10::optional<at::MemoryFormat> memory_format=c10::nullopt) {
    return at::_ops::empty_memory_format::call(c10::fromIntArrayRefSlow(size), optTypeMetaToScalarType(options.dtype_opt()), options.layout_opt(), options.device_opt(), options.pinned_memory_opt(), c10::impl::check_tensor_options_and_extract_memory_format(options, memory_format));
}
```